# Redefine Required Property of referenced JSON Schema

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

My schema uses `"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",` and contains the following in its `definitions`:

```
"lineitem": {
    "name": "Item",
    "description": "Single item found in an order.",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": true,
    "allOf":[{ "ref": "../line-item.json" }]
}
```

My issue is this: I need everything in this `line-item.json`, except for one required property `status` which is an enum which is useless to me. I need to be able to override `status`, without changing the referenced schema. I do need a status, and I have a definitions file which has the proper information. But how do I pull it into my item? `status` is required for both items, but has different meanings.

I have tried these two which both fail, and I feel like this must be possible but I'm doing something wrong:

```
"lineitem": {
    "name": "Item",
    "description": "Single item found in an order.",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": true,
    "allOf":[{ "ref": "../line-item.json" }],
    "properties": {
        "status": { "$ref": "definitions.json#/definitions/status" }
    }
}

"lineitem": {
    "name": "Item",
    "description": "Single item found in an order.",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": true,
    "allOf":[{ "ref": "../line-item.json" }],
    "definitions": {
        "status": { "$ref": "definitions.json#/definitions/status" }
    }
},
```

I'm fully aware that the best way to solve this problem would be to redefine `line-item.json` so that `status` is either not required, or has different definitions for each use, which the user of the `line-item` schema would choose on use. But I don't have the authority to change that schema, and the buy-in from the many affected users of this schema would be difficult to obtain.

Answer (score 2):

All the constraints in JSON Schema are additive, it means you can not remove what was added but instead you need to leverage composition from beginning. My suggestion is to split `line-item.json`.

`line-item.json`:

```
{
  "allOf": {
    "properties": {
      "status": {"enum": [1,2,3]}
    },
    "allOf": {
      "$ref": "line-item-without-status.json"
    }
  }
}
```

Line item with another status definition:

```
{
  "allOf": {
    "properties": {
      "status": {"$ref": "#/definitions/status"}
    },
    "allOf": {
      "$ref": "line-item-without-status.json"
    }
  }
}
```

Shared `line-item-without-status.json`:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "sharedProp": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate your comment?

Comment: Your advice is to split line-item.json, but as I said in the OP, I don't have the authority to change the line-item schema.  You are right, that you have the best solution. But with the constraints of our internal politics and our system architecture, I can't do that. I wound up making a "historyLineitem" schema, and referencing the definitions of all the properties except status. It will be a nightmare to maintain if anything needs to be added, but maybe then someone will support the very simple change needed to line-item.json so that status is oneOf.